# Static Class vs Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

So, pretty simple question.  Ignoring the implications of over-use of the singleton pattern.  I'm trying to find a reliable singleton patter in Objective-C.  I have come across this:

```
@implementation SomeSingleTonClass

static SomeSingleTonClass* singleInstance;

+ (SomeSingleTonClass*)getInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t dispatchOnceToken;

    dispatch_once(&dispatchOnceToken, ^{
        singleInstance = [[SomeSingleTonClass alloc] init];
    });

    return singleInstance;
}

- (void)someMethodOnTheInstance
{
    NSLog(@"DO SOMET WORK")
}

@end
```

This I am fairly happy with but it leads to a lot of this:

```
[[SomeSingleTonClass getInstance] someMethodOnTheInstance];
```

My question is, why is this better than a purely static class.

```
@implementation SomeStaticClass

static NSString* someStaticStateVariable;

- (id)init
{
    //Don't allow init to initialize any memory state
    //Perhaps throw an exception to let some other programmer know
    //not to do this
    return nil;
}

+ (void)someStaticMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Do Some Work");
}
```

All you really gain, is mildly cleaner looking method calls.  Basically you swap out this:

```
[[SomeSingleTonClass getInstance] someMethodOnTheInstance];
```

For this

```
[SomeStaticClass someStaticMethod];
```

This is a minor simplification for sure, and you can always store the instance within your class.  This is more intellectual curiosity, what Objective-C god am I pissing off by using static classes instead of singletons?  I'm sure I can't be the first person to think this, but I promise, I did a duplicate search first.  The few answers I found, I felt like were based on older versions of cocoa, because even the discussed singleton patterns seemed to suffer from threading issues.

Comment: I think you're right, but that question is kinda convoluted(though the answer is solid!).  I'm going to leave mine up, but given the answers in that thread, I don't need to wait for upvotes on Drummer's answer.  It's correct.  Thanks!

Comment: What's a static class?

Comment: A static class(there's probably a better name) is a class that relies on class methods, and static class variables, rather than an instantiated object and instance methods.  This is what makes it a convenient singleton.  Particularly if you code your init method to throw an exception!

Comment: Although I doubt you're annoying any ObjC gods (at least not much ;-)  ), 'static class' is the wrong nomenclature -- there's no such thing in Objective-C.

Comment: As a corollary, Objective-C has class methods but there's no such thing in Objective-C as a static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pissing off no Objective-C gods with a class like that. Actually, Apple recommends to use that pattern in some cases (I think they mentioned this in one of the ARC session videos, where they discussed common design patterns and how to implement them using ARC).

In other cases, where you can have multiple instances of a class, but want a default one, you'll of course have to use the shared instance approach.

Comment: Essentially correct.  Also, see the answer in the "duplicate" link Martin provided for repercussions of each.  It would appear neither approach is factually better or worse, just different.

Comment: One thing that no one has pointed out is that a non-trivial singleton (as opposed to a static class) can do a lot more things, since it is a legitimate instance.  Register for notification, be key-value-observed, used as a datasource, etc.

Comment: When you say "that pattern", which friggin' pattern are you talking about? lol. He put two different patterns in the post.

Answer (score 20):

**Static class** : Used when you want to group together utility methods that are state independent.

**Singleton** : Used when you have multiple methods that share a state.

Answer (score 3):

I've found it convenient to do a mix of both. I use a standard singleton pattern similar to your first that results in:

```
[[MyClass defaultInstance] doSomething];
```

But I also want to be able to create other instances of the same class:

```
MyClass *secondInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[secondInstance doSomething];
```

When I want more concise access to call methods on the singleton instance, I define class methods as follows:

```
// class method to call a method on the singleton instance
+ (void)doSomething
{
    [[MyClass defaultInstance] doSomething];
}
```

So with that, I can use:

```
[MyClass doSomething];
```

Answer (score 1):

The first example seems to be needlessly creating a singleton-like instance of a class. I say needlessly because from your other comments it appears that the class doesn't declare any properties or instance variables. Given that the fundamental purpose of an object is to provide storage for state, an object with no instance variables is rarely a useful thing.

Your second example shows a class that would never be instantiated. Again, the fundamental purpose of a class in Objective-C is to act as a factory for instances, so a class that's never instantiated isn't really useful or necessary.

Instead, you can just provide a set of C functions. C functions don't need to be associated with a class at all. So consider doing something like this:

```
static NSString* someStaticStateVariable;

void someFunction(void)
{
    NSLog(@"Do Some Work");
}
```

The functions can be in separate .h/.m pair, or can be incorporated in the .h/.m for an existing class if it makes sense to do so (generally, if the functions are closely associated with the concerns of that class).

Comment: The demonstrations of the class was to demonstrate the design patterns I was considering only, not the use I was considering for them.  I of course expect my classes to have much more state than I presented in my simplified examples, for the sake of the stack overflow question.

Comment: @ChrisCM You seem to be saying your instances will have state, but in your second example, you override `init` to disable creating instances, so obviously there's no possibility of having objects with state. You can't add state to a class, so all that's left is global variables. Again, you don't need classes and methods to use global variables, so why not just use C functions?

Comment: I guess ultimately it doesn't answer the question.  Both solutions suffer from potentially the same flaw, that is storing state in static global variables.  It is this "why/why not?" that I'm curious about, not how.  So, in answer to why not use plain C functions?  Because, associating something to a class is inherently useful for clearer understanding of code. [MyDatabaseClass someFunction] tells me a lot more about what's going on than someFunction().